# Экспорт JavaFX приложения на DVD

Tags: javafx, java

Добрый вечер!

Нужна помощь! Нужно записать на DVD диск Java приложение вместе со средой. Так чтобы Java читалась с диска и не требовалось устанавливать ее на компьютер.

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: С его помощью создал exe фаил. А как записать, все это, на диск не могу понять...

Comment: @post_zeew Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.

Comment: Я решил проблему с помощью .bat файла. Если нужно более подробный ответ - обращайтесь.